# Reference for the positive probability of convergence to a stable point of a stochastic approximation algorithm

Tags: stochastic-processes, limits-and-convergence, stochastic-approximation

Consider a stochastic approximation process with 
$$x_{t+1} = x_t + \frac{1}{t} (g(x_t)+u_t)$$
where $(u_s)_s$ is a sequence of i.i.d. shocks.
Assume $g$ is Lipschitz, $u_t$ has finite variance, and that 
$(x_s)_s$ is bounded with probability one.
Furthermore, assume that 
$$
C = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \colon g(x)=0\}
$$
is finite.

In this case it follows from the results in stochastic approximation theory that $x$ converges a.s. to a point in $C$ (see for example Kushner and Yin, ``Stochastic Approximation and Recursive Algorithms and Applications'' Theorem 2.1 page 127).

**Question:** Do you know a reference that provides conditions such that $x$ converges to a given point in $C$ with strictly positive probability.

Comment: There seems to be an error in your definition of stable points.

Comment: Thanks a lot, corrected.

Comment: I still don't think it is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot Piyush, could you explain what the problem is, I am sorry if I miss something obvious.

Comment: I don't understand it. The term g(x)(x-y) cannot be positive for all y close to x, since suppose $y_1>x$, then it requires g(x)<0, but then for $y_2<x$ close to x, it gives $g(x)(x-y_2)<0$.

Comment: Thanks sorry this was a typo I confused y and x. It should be g(y) not g(x) corrected.

Comment: Can you point out where in the Kushner/Yin book is this definition of stability given ?

Comment: You are completely right this is not in Theorem 2.1, in the book section 5.8 briefly discusses ruling out unstable points, but this needs an additional continuity assumption on the distribution of $u$. I adjusted the question accordingly.